# PulseAudio equalizer distortion (16.04 LTS)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, equalizer

Is there anything I can do to eliminate the distortion at 100% volume that happens when using `PulseAudio Equalizer` and presets like Laptop, Headphones, Rock, etc.?

> 00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller
>   (rev 09)

[image]

Comment: The only workaround I know is to reduce the volume in the music application itself; e.g. Spotify at 50% volume eliminates most of the distortion for me.